# Find First Element With Data Attribute Greater Than Zero JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of divs with the class `.item-wrap`

Currently, I select the first div using the following code

```
$(".item-wrap:first").trigger( "click" );
```

Each `.item-wrap` has a `data-amount` attribute.

How can I modify my current code to select the first `.item-wrap` that has `data-amount` greater than 0?

Answer (score 5):

Using the `filter` function, we can restrict our search. To select an element by it's data-attribute, jQuery has a handy `data()` function.

This may show up multiple results, as in my example. To get the first one, you can use the `first` method.

```js
$("div").filter(function() {
  return $(this).data("amount") > 0;
}).first().css({"color": "green"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-amount="-7">On Tuesday I lost 7 dollars gambling</div>
<div data-amount="-3">On Wednesday, I lost 3 dollars gambling</div>
<div data-amount="37">On Thursday, I actually won 37 dollars</div>
<div data-amount="16">I'm on a roll. Won 16 more dollars today</div>
```

**Some Notes**

- If your data-attribute does not consist solely of numbers, this code will not work. This is assuming all of your `data-amounts` have a value that matches the regular expression: `\A\d*\z`
- A string can be compared against a number if the string matched a particular pattern. This is because JavaScript performs automatic type conversion. In this example, it's fairly trivial because we don't have a lot of data. However, if you had many more divs, you might want to do something like `+$(this).data("amount") > 0`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `each()` to iterate over the elements and exit from loop by using `return false;`

```
$('.item-wrap').each(function() {
    if (+$(this).data('amount') > 0) {
        // Do "Hello World" here
        $(this).trigger('click');

        // Breakout
        return false;
    }
});
```